# How can I find which website has this error?

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, application-pools

Server OS is: Windows 2003 R2 X64
Webserver is: IIS 6

There is an error in Event log:

It is not possible to run two different versions of ASP.NET in the same IIS process. Please use the IIS Administration Tool to reconfigure your server to run the application in a separate process.

I have a lot of websites, how can I find this error related to which website or application pool?

Answer (score 0):

I have just run into this error, the quickest thing for me was to run this:

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -lk
```

This produces a list of the websites and which .NET versions they are using. I then checked the application pool of those listed to verify which has a problem.

I'd love a solution that just pointed right at the answer but this certainly helped.